# The page shows data before i click the search button Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes, controller

Im new on laravel
im working on a project.
the problem is when i enter the page all the data is there and i only want them to be shown when i search.
when i click search it's working i can only see one

so the problem is how can i block the data to be shown before i search.

thank you. here's my code

```
public function Newtask(Request $request){
    // $clients = Client::all();
    // return view('receptions.newtask',compact('clients'));
    $recherche = $request->get('ClientSearchbylastname');
    $clients =  Client::where([['ClientLastName','LIKE','%'.$recherche.'%']])->get();

    return view('receptions.newtask',compact('clients'));

}
```

Comment: Anyway, just make it not do the search when `$recherche` is empty. Set `$clients` to be an empty array in that situation, instead.

Answer (score 0):

If not `$recherche` set `$clients` as an empty array.

```php
$clients = $recherche ? Cliente::where([['ClientLastName', 'LIKE', '%'.$recherche.'%']])->get() : [];
```

PD: Next time, paste code instead of image.